# Add Sections in an Array in Table View in iOS

Tags: swift, tableview

I'm calling an API, getting an array in response, and then populating that array in my table view. Now I want that if the array has 2 elements or more, then each element should be shown under a single section of table view. Section will have some title also. How I can do this with existing array? For example, I receive `array["A","B"]`. Now when table view should load it should show element "A" under section1 and element "B" should be shown under section2. How this could be happen with an array I'm getting from response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In order to have a section for each array element, `return array.count` in `func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView)`
2. Set `return 1` in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
   numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)`
3. Specify cell value as `array[indexPath.section]` in `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

Comment: How i can show section title as if array element 1 then sectio 1 and if array element 2 then section title 2? .@DevKyle

Comment: Thanks for your help your were the first to tell about this concept on this question. @DevKyle

Answer (score 2):

Take initially array with 1 elements , initially do `array.append("");`., and return `array.count` in `numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int` function.

```swift
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return array.count
}
```

read your api data into same array object & Once your API call completed you can reload tableView data  using `tableView.reloadData()`
Use this array inside `titleForHeaderInSection section`

```swift
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {       
    return array[section]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should return the total array count in `numberOfSection` if you want to show a section for each element. I have also added code for adding a title in the section header.

```swift
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return myArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView()
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

    let headerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 0, width:
        tableView.bounds.size.width, height: tableView.bounds.size.height))
    headerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 20)
    headerLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    headerLabel.text = "Section: \(section+1)"
    headerLabel.sizeToFit()
    headerView.addSubview(headerLabel)

    return headerView
}
```

Comment: I want to show section title like if array element is first then title should be section1 and so for next section2. How i can make this as section title?. @OSArchitect.com

Comment: updated my code. headerLabel.text = "Section: \(section)"

Comment: For this headerLabel.text = myArray[section] it will show section title 0 at first. @iOSArchitect.com